# C# Background worker not completing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I'm having issues with my background worker not completing and subsequently hanging after one run. The background worker handles a program running a linear stage and so it is important that the timing is right (hence all of the `Thread.Sleep()` calls.)

here is my code:

```
public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bgW2.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgW2_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }
private void bgW2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string program = @"C:\Users\mikegjohn\source\repos\CLL AutoForce\Test.csv";
            var stream = new FileStream(program, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string ln;
                while ((ln = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] lnArr = ln.Split(',');

                    switch (lnArr[1])
                    {
                        case "0":

                            sendCommand("L-");
                            string status = "";
                            while (status != "0")
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(250);
                                status = loopCommands("PS");
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            break;

                        case "1":
                            string p = Fn.convertPos(lnArr[3]);
                            sendCommand("X"+p);
                            string s = Convert.ToString(Fn.backconvert(loopCommands("PX")));

                            while (s != lnArr[3])
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(250);
                                s = Convert.ToString(Fn.backconvert(loopCommands("PX")));
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            Fn.MeasureLabel();
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            sendCommand("HSPD=500000");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            sendCommand("LSPD=250000");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            sendCommand("X0");
                            string x = Convert.ToString(Fn.backconvert(loopCommands("PX")));

                            while (x != lnArr[4])
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(250);
                                s = Convert.ToString(Fn.backconvert(loopCommands("PX")));
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            sendCommand("HSPD=250000");
                            sendCommand("LSPD=50000");
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }

        }


private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bgW2.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bgW2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Program completed");
    }
```

The `Messagebox.Show` never fires. I have taken a look at some other similar issues with this which points mainly to blocking of the UI thread. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my issue - it was a bug in `case "3"` which i was not picking up

```
case "3":
                            sendCommand("HSPD=500000");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            sendCommand("LSPD=250000");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            sendCommand("X0");
                            string x = Convert.ToString(Fn.backconvert(loopCommands("PX")));

                            while (x != lnArr[4])
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(250);
                                s = Convert.ToString(Fn.backconvert(loopCommands("PX"))); // <-- this does not match the while so it was getting stuck in the loop 
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            sendCommand("HSPD=250000");
                            sendCommand("LSPD=50000");
                            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing the DoWork event.

```
public Form1() { 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    bgW2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgW2_DoWork) ;
    bgW2.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgW2_RunWorkerCompleted);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14734610

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i have popped this in but i am afraid nothing has changed.